# Flex/Bison : Generic way to tokenize keywords separated by whitespaces/tabs

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am writing a program which allows command (basically a string till newline) containing multiple parameters which are space separated.

```
Like: arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 (\n)
```

I can use regex itself to achieve this as below:

```
arg1[ \t]+    {return T_ARG1;}
arg2[ \t]+    {return T_ARG2;}
arg3[ \t]+    {return T_ARG3;}
arg4[ \t]+    {return T_ARG4;}
```

But I am not sure that is it the best way to do it like that?
Can you please suggest a generic way to it in Flex?

Note: I also allow command typed across multiple  lines by ignoring [\\n] pattern.

Comment: Are the arguments really keywords? Or are they arbitrary whitespace separated words? In other words, are you trying to recognize a set of fixed words in any order, or create a vector of arguments in the order they were entered?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to recognize a set of fixed words in some order.

Comment: I am trying to create a command (like a linux command) interpreter using flex and bison. The order is:
arg1 <space> arg2 <space> arg3 <space> arg4
Note: <space> means minimum one space.

Answer (score 1):

using `arg1[ \t]+` is not a good idea, because you are returning a 'dirty' token- your desired token with excess whitespaces, and you might want to remove them later (that means more parsing).

Remember that flex is greedy:

> [If it finds more than one match, it takes the one matching the most text (for trailing context rules, this includes the length of the trailing part, even though it will then be returned to the input). If it finds two or more matches of the same length, the rule listed first in the flex input file is chosen.](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html)

so it will try to match the **largest text**, and it will consider pattern order **only** in case of length equality. So you need to prioritize your args, then put a pattern that will match the rest of the words:

```
WHITESPACE    [\t\n\r ]
DIGIT         [0-9]
LETTER        [a-zA-Z]
%%
arg1                  return T_ARG1;
arg2                  return T_ARG2;
arg3                  return T_ARG3;
arg4                  return T_ARG4;
(LETTER|DIGIT|[_])+   printf("error! unknown command\n");
WHITESPACE            ;
%%
```

You can use `[:digit:]` or just `[0-9]` instead of `DIGIT` i defined, see [here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) for more standard expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that the separators are included in the lexeme? Usually it is not, and we can just discard any of the separators leaving the tokens for the arguments themselves:

```
[ \t\n\r]+      ; /* Skip */
arg1        return T_ARG1;
arg2        return T_ARG2;
arg3        return T_ARG3;
arg4        return T_ARG4;
```

Comment: For example,
ip addradd (in inux gives me an error)
Object "addradd" is unknown, try "ip help". Because there has to be a space in between addr and add.

Comment: I tried your code too. But it accepts arg1arg2arg3arg4 also which I do not want. I want atleast one space between two words.